# Hibernate Updates Data When Calling Setter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an encrypted value in database and I would like to decrypt it before sending to front-end. 
When I first save the value as encrypted, it looks like `-kKwj477382jle34nw` in database. But if I call my `getClientByUsername()` function which I make the decryption thing in this function, the value in database also changes itself automatically when I set decrypted value in the object before sending the object to front-end.

```
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity <Client> getClientByUsername(String username) throws Exception {
  Client loggedClient = clientDAO.findByUsername(username);
  String data = loggedClient.getCreditCardNo();
  if (null != data) {
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    byte[] encrypted = base64.decodeBase64(data);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), algorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    loggedClient.setCreditCardNo(new String(decrypted));
  }
  return new ResponseEntity < Client > (loggedClient, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is how I save the value as encrypted:

```
@Transactional
public boolean clientUpdate(String client) {
    str = updateclient.getCreditCardNo();
    if (null != str) {
      SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), algorithm);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
      encrypted = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      updateclient.setCreditCardNo(base64.encodeToString(encrypted));
      return clientDAO.updateProfileClient(updateclient);
    }
```

How can I block hibernate to change the value when calling setter?

**Update**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public Client findByUsername(String username) throws Exception {
      Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Client.findByUsername");
      query.setParameter("username", username);
      List result = query.getResultList();
      return result.size() > 0 ? (Client) result.get(0) : null;
    }
```

Comment: this is one fine example of why you should separate your entity from your dto for response. edit: and controller logic from transactional logic too

Comment: @Zeromus not necessary. I personally hate this separation and always fight against it in projects.

Comment: suppose it's a preference after all... but i find it much cleaner to separate logic and avoid these kind of problems when building responses

Comment: Yep, and then introduce tons of errors while copying properties from one object to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [evict](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object)) this object from Hibernate's session:

```
void evict(Object object) throws HibernateException
```

> Remove this instance from the session cache. Changes to the instance
>   will not be synchronized with the database. This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   cascade="evict".

P.S. Just thought, that you can also consider another approach. You can create a field in bean which will be marked as `@Transient`, i.e. decoupled from the database, and name it, say, `creditCardNoDecrypted`. The encrypted field mark as `@JsonIngore` (or whatever you use for serialisation).

Comment: I believe using evict is better approach but I haven't figured out how I can do it

Comment: This  should be done in `clientDAO.findByUsername` method

Comment: I updated my answer by adding `findByUsername` function. I am using `EntityManager`. I think I need to have `hibernate.cfg.xml` to use `SessionFactory` which is needed by `Session`, but I don't have it. So does `entityManager.refresh(obj)` do the same thing like `evict(Object obj)` does or what should I do?

Comment: For JPA use `entityManager.detach(object)`

Comment: Thanks! It works with `entityManager.detach(object)`. What should I read to have knowledge about these stuff?